# Developing on Xamarin Studio with GTK#, how to see error message? (windows)

Tags: xamarin-studio, gtk#

When trying to develop a cross platform GUI application on Windows, it seems whenever there's an error, the problem just closes with no information on what's wrong whatsoever.

How do i get my error messages?

Comment: Is the code your running release or debug? If debug, are you running it in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running it from the command line. Or change the compiler options for the project so the Compile Target is Executable instead of Executable with GUI, which should run it with a command prompt.